# VideoJS Resolution Switcher reports "this.updateSrc is not a function"

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am randomly facing this error. Sometimes video loads fine but mostly it shows "updateSrc is not a function". Video usually loads on page refresh. I have tried everything but couldn't fix this.

HTML

```
<video id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="video-js vjs-16-9 vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" poster="<?php echo (isset($mPoster))?$mPoster:'';?>" data-setup="{}">
                        <p class="vjs-no-js">
                            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                        </p>
                    </video>
```

JavaScript

```
var videoplayer = videojs('<?php echo $id; ?>', {
            plugins: {
                videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
                    default: 480,
                    dynamicLabel: true
                }
            }
        }, function() {
            this.updateSrc(<?php echo (isset($code))?$code:'';?>)
            this.preload(false)
            this.on('resolutionchange', function() {
                console.info('Source changed to %s', this.src())
            })
            this.autoplay(true)
        });
```

Error

[image: Console Error]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix by dynamically generating the video tag.
Here is the code:

```
 var videotaghtml= "<video id='<?php echo $id; ?>' class='video-js vjs-16-9 vjs-big-play-centered'"+ " controls preload='auto' width='100%' height='100%' poster='<?php echo (isset($mPoster))?$mPoster:'';?>'"+ "data-setup=\"{}\">"+
        "<p class=\"vjs-no-js\">"+
        "To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that"+
        "<a href=\"http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/\" target=\"_blank\">supports HTML5 video</a>"+
        "</p>"+
        +"</video>";

 $( "#videotag" ).append(videotaghtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue before.

I believe it is because of `data-setup={}` in your code. Due to this, the plugins in javascript is not initialized as **videojs** considers only either data-setup or plugins.

Sometimes it considers `data-setup={}`. Thus, the videojs resolution switcher which contains the updateSrc method is not called. Hence the error. Just remove `data-setup={}` and it should be fine.